# Prevent <span> from resizing when textContent is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom button class that uses a `<span>`, and I'm changing the text of the button temporarily when the button is clicked.

```js
const three = document.getElementById('three');
three.addEventListener('click', () => {
  three.textContent = 'Clicked!';
  setTimeout(() => {
    three.textContent = 'Three';
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.controls {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <span class="button">One</span>
  <span class="button">Two</span>
  <span class="button" id="three">Three</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the temporary text has a different length, which causes the span to resize and then the whole panel of buttons shifts slightly to recenter.

What's the best way to prevent this resize and make sure the button has enough space for either string? I tried playing around with putting both of the strings as child `<span>` elements with one hidden, but I couldn't figure how to get them to overlap properly.

Comment: Set the elements to be a fixed size in CSS perhaps? `.button { width: 100px; }`

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't seem to have any affect?

Also I wouldn't want all of the buttons to be the same size, although I suppose it wouldn't be hard to have a separate class for this particular button.

Comment: You would also need `display: inline-block`

Comment: Ah, that does the trick! OK I think I can make this work with an extra class for buttons that need to do this. Thanks!